# How to take backup of MySQL database in Bluemix?

Tags: mysql, backup, ibm-cloud

I am using IBM Bluemix MySQL database as a DB server, but I don't know how to take backup from it.

In the past I used to do that with CF tunneling option, but the new CF tool doesn't support CF tunnel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some services, like the experimental `mysql` service on Bluemix are not able to be accessed from outside of Bluemix. You can only access them from within a Bluemix cloud foundry application. If you are using this service , you will need to deploy a [phpmyadmin](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/phpmyadmin-cf) application and bind it to that database to perform management operations.

If you are using other mysql services like cleardb, see Jeff's answer

Answer (score 2):

You will need to get the connection information for the database.  You can get this from the UI or the command line.

If you do this from the command line, run `cf e appname`.  It will return the connection information for the db.  You can also get it from the UI, if you click on "Show Credentials" it will give you the connection information as well.

Once you get this you can use any MySQL browser to grab the data.  You can also grab it with the following command.

```
mysqldump [options] db_name
```

See [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) for more info.